# Not linking another page by path in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, single-page-application

I use $location.path() to add there data `@object` and by submitting a form there is:`url.com/@object`, but when reloading the page - page is not found: i need not open another page, i just need to reload url.com with this parameter `@object`. How is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your page is not found is most likely because there is no `route` defined that matches the `path` with your data object.

If you want to pass data from within the URL, while still matching your routes, there are a few ways to do it.

1. `$routeParams`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

```
// Given:
// URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
// Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
//
// Then
$routeParams ==> {chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'}
```

2. `$location.hash()`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#hash

```
// given URL http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo#hashValue
var hash = $location.hash();
// => "hashValue"
```

3. `$location.search()`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search

```
// given URL http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var searchObject = $location.search();
// => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}

// set foo to 'yipee'
$location.search('foo', 'yipee');
// $location.search() => {foo: 'yipee', baz: 'xoxo'}
```

However, it may be better to user a `Service` to store data.  In AngularJS, services are `Singleton`s which mean that they are instantiated once, and are great for storing `state` and/or `data`.

[More info on how to use services.](https://rclayton.silvrback.com/passing-state-via-services)

Please let me know if you have any questions.